# Efficient, URL-safe two-way text-encoding

Tags: encoding, compression

I feel like I end up having to do this a lot.  I've got some chunk of data, say a series of products to display on a page.  My URL looks something like this:

http://mywebsite.com/displayproducts/?p=product_id1,product_id2,product_id3,product_id4

I want to anonymize that product list so it's not a readable URL.  It doesn't have to be crypto-safe, but I just don't want users to be able to read the data straight from the URL.

I'd like something that looks "random", a la:

http://mywebsite.com/displayproducts/?p=X298Xjijdf088DFhj781hJhk1

...but decodes to product_id1,product_id2,product_id3,product_id4

Typically, I'll just compress the string and then base64 encode it, but I'm wondering if there's a smarter way.  I want to avoid keeping state in the backend or coming up with some scheme to assign integer values to each product id.  I'm looking for a general text->text solution, regardless of the nature of the data.

Comment: Have you considered using hidden field values on an HTML form instead of encoding it all into the URL?

Comment: I want a get request so I can re-use the URL elsewhere.  All state should be in the URL.

Comment: Is there anything less than ideal about the base-64 solution you are using?  It seems pretty "smart" already to me.  What would you be looking to improve about it?  Just wondering if it can be even shorter/smaller?